# How to quickly check, if a given variable has many levels?

Tags: r, data.table

I write a script that helps to verify structure and do basic descriptive statistics of a very large data.tables. I need to have a fast way to tell if a given variable has more than - say - 50 unique levels.

I might do it by

```
function(DT, colnr)
{
    b<-DT[, list(var=colnames(DT)[[colnr]],.N), by = list(level=DT[[colnr]])]
    if(nrow(b)<50) 
        #less than 50 levels, probably we need a dictionary.
        setorder(b, level)
        b
    else
        #more than 50 levels. Just return the number of unique values.
        data.table(level=NA, var=colnames(DT)[[colnr]], N=-nrow(b))
}
```

but `DT[, list(var=colnames(DT)[[colnr]],.N), by = list(level=DT[[colnr]])]` takes very long for variables with as many unique values as there are cases (I have over 4 million of cases in `DT`)

Is there a way to improve the performance? I don't need to count the number of unique cases if there is more then 50 of them. Returning "more than 50" would suffice.

Comment: Or maybe `nlevels` (not sure about speed though)

Comment: `nlevels` doesn't count the actual values - it only takes into consideration variable's attributes. OTOH combining my function with `uniqueN` executes in less than a half on the real world data.table. Wow!! Thank you!

Comment: @AdamRyczkowski you can self answer your question. `?uniqueN` fully describes your case.

Comment: btw, if you're passing a column number, you can just do `DT[ , colnr, with = FALSE]`

Comment: n_distinct() from dplyr is also a great option.